# Toggle loop when a key is pressed?

Tags: loops, toggle, autohotkey

For instance, pressing TAB would turn off/on this loop:

```
Loop
{ ;loop start
    GetKeyState, var, LButton, P
    If var = U
        Break
    Send {1}
    Random, r, 100, 400
    sleep r
}
return
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this:

```
Tab:: toggle := !toggle

#If toggle

~LButton::
while GetKeyState("LButton")
{
    Send {1}
    Random, r, 100, 400
    sleep r
}
return

#If
```

Comment: It works, but after a few seconds it reverts back to loop state.

Comment: Could it be that your mouse driver needs to be updated?. Replace in the script "~LButton::" by "F1::" and "while GetKeyState("LButton")" by "while GetKeyState("F1", "P")" and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

## Example with settimer

```
Settimer, MyLabel, 10

Tab::
Settimer, MyLabel, % (t:=!t)?"On":"Off"
Return

MyLabel::
    GetKeyState, var, LButton, P
    If var = U
        Settimer,, Off
    Send {1}
    Random, r, 100, 400
    sleep r
return
```